# Access Internal PDF links from html text block inside pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using itext 5. I have a string with HTML styling in it and a link to go to chapter 2 in pdf.

`String text = "<p><strong>Jack </strong>and <strong>Jill </strong>went up the hill, then down the hill, around the hill then to <a href="Chapter 2">Chater 2</a>.</p>";`

I am using HTMLWorker to parse html to string and setting the local destination for chapter 2 using chunk with localGoto.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class InternalLinkExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document();

        try {

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("InternalLink.pdf"));

            String text = "<p><strong>Jack </strong>and <strong>Jill </strong>went up the hill, then down the hill, around the hill then to <a href=#\"Chapter2\">Chater 2</a>.</p>";

            document.open();

            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            try {
                htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(text));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            document.newPage();

            Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Chapter 2 Jack");
            chunk.setLocalDestination("Chapter2");  
            document.add(chunk);

            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I generate a pdf with the given string using iText and open PDF internal links in adobe PDF viewer it throws a security warning and doesn't open. However, I'm able to access link when I open pdf using google chrome.

I want to access internal links using adobe pdf viewer. So please let me know how to access the internal link from Html string. Also, I'm upgrading to Itext 7, It will be helpful if the solution works on Itext 7.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you simply converting HTML to PDF, or just using HTML to elements conversion to apply some styling to elements while generating the document by your own? Or do you modify an existing document?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I'm just using HTML for elements conversion to apply some styling to elements while generating the pdf.

Comment: @AlexeySubach I have updated the question with actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in iText 7 looks pretty similar to the code in iText 5. Make sure that the hash symbol (`#`) is included into the `href` attribute value (inside double quotes), i.e. `<a href="#Chapter2">`

Here is the full code of how to generate a link to the anchor in iText 7. The link in the resultant document works fine in Acrobat.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("C:/path/to.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

String text = "<p><strong>Jack </strong>and <strong>Jill </strong>went up the hill, then down the hill, around the hill then to <a href=\"#Chapter2\">Chapter 2</a>.</p>";

List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(text);

for (IElement element : elements) {
    if (element instanceof IBlockElement) {
        document.add((IBlockElement) element);
    }
}

document.add(new AreaBreak());

Text chapterTitle = new Text("Chapter 2 Jack").setDestination("Chapter2");
document.add(new Paragraph(chapterTitle));

document.close();
```